# How build multiple projects with gradle with multiple jdk versions?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have multiple projects and build using different jdks(IBM,SUN) and versions(1.6,1.7,1.8).

In my gradle script of the each project I have defined the sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility. How can I define the each project specific `org.gradle.java.home`?

If I define the IBM jdk 6 as `org.gradle.java.home` in my main project `gradle.properties` file other projects build will fail.

I have `gradle.properties` file only main gradle project.

I don't want to use JAVA_HOME class path variable to run my gradle scripts.
I'm using gradle 2.3.

Please give some advice to fix this issue?

Comment: Use the if else condition to change java version based on the project. E.g if you have Project A , B  & C in build xml you define java home path as null and base on the project you change the java home. I think this will help you to solve your issue.

Comment: @stacktome I'm using gradle. How can I add it? can you give some sample?

Comment: Your only bet is to modify the `JavaCompile` task. In 2.3 you have to look at the poorly documented `JavaToolChain`: https://docs.gradle.org/2.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile:toolChain and https://docs.gradle.org/2.3/javadoc/org/gradle/jvm/toolchain/JavaToolChain.html But the tool chain has been replaced by the even more poorly documented tool resolver from 2.4: https://docs.gradle.org/2.4/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile:toolResolver

Answer (score 5):

Since Gradle 6.7, Gradle introduced the notion of [*toolchains* for the JVM](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/toolchains.html). *Toolchains* allow to define a JDK version to be used to compile/run a project, that is a JDK different than the one running gradle.

This is as easy as writing in the build script :

```
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(15)
    }
}
```

Gradle will look up the requested toolchain on usual standard local paths (and you can evn provide your own lookup location via the `org.gradle.java.installations.paths` property), and can eventually download it. It even support multiple OpenJDK vendors. Their [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/toolchains.html) explains it all.

So for a multi-project setup, you can do something like :

```
.
├── jdk11
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
├── jdk16
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
├── jdk17
│   ├── build.gradle
│   └── src
├── build.gradle
├── gradle.properties
└── settings.gradle
```

- `settings.gradle`

  ```
  rootProject.name = 'THE-project'    
  include("jdk11", "jdk16", "jdk17")
  ```
- `build.gradle`

  ```
  subprojects {
    apply(plugin: "java-library") // or whatever applies to the sub-project

    // repositories, test, ...
  }
  ``
  ```
- `gradle.properties` the property is optional, it is only if additional lookup path are needed

  ```
  org.gradle.java.installations.paths=/path to panama jdk,/path to loom jdk,etc
  ```
- `jdk11/build.gradle`

  ```
  java {
    toolchain {
      languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(11)
    }
  }

  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.release.set(11)
  }

  // dependencies, etc.
  ```
- `jdk16/build.gradle`

  ```
  java {
    toolchain {
      languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(16)
    }
  }

  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.release.set(16)
  }

  // dependencies, etc.
  ```
- `jdk17/build.gradle`

  ```
  java {
    toolchain {
      languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(17)
    }
  }

  tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.release.set(17)
    options.compilerArgs = ['--add-modules=jdk.incubator.foreign',
                            '--enable-preview',
                            '-Xlint:preview']
  }

  // dependencies, etc.
  ```

I don't know about Eclipse, but this work just fine in IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.
I use a JDK 11 to run gradle in the shell, and IntelliJ IDEA is setup to run Gradle with JDK 11 as well (*Settings | Build tools | Gradle*).

---

The only downside at the moment is that `JavaExec` tasks must be configured with the right launcher (eg using the (sub-)project's toolchain). IntelliJ runs main class using a JavaExec task, which will benefit form this as well.

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec){
    javaLauncher.set(javaToolchains.launcherFor(java.toolchain))
}
```

Track [gradle/gradle#14363](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/14363) on this matter.

---

Comment: So I'm a little confused.  I see (/jdk11/src/ and /jdk16/src/ and /jdk17/src).  If I have a .java file like "MyCoolHelperMethods.java"......how would I have one copy of this file..that gets compiled to different JDKs?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @granadaCoder That's a different question. The current answer is about multiple projects. If your project require to be compiled by different JDKs then you need to register different compile tasks. I'll be happy to answer this in another question, but it's likely such aquestion has already been asked.

Comment: Thanks for the "hint".  I'll fish around.

Comment: Have you found a good answer to the above, @granadaCoder ? I also am looking for ways on how to compile one src to multiple java target versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a gradle master or expert but,

actually you should consider two things about gradle:

If you want to use gradle.properties to compile your projects against specific JVM's, you should know,

> "...The configuration is applied in following order (if an option is
>   configured in multiple locations the last one wins):
>
> from gradle.properties in project build dir. 
>  
>   from gradle.properties in gradle user home. 
>   from system properties, e.g. when -Dsome.property is
>   set on the command line."

in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#build_environment

Second, if you want to configure your compilers on the fly, this might help you,

```
apply plugin: "java"
   sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["MyProject/src"]
   dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: "MyProject/lib/jar")
   }
   tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
       options.fork = true
       options.forkOptions.executable = "path/to/javac"
   }
```